# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How I check if the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{2}}$ is convergent or divergent??

I tried few tests, but I didn't success to discover if the series  is convergent or is divergent...

**I need to use one of the tests to show it...**

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{2}}$$

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand your answer...

Comment: This question has already been asked on this website. If you don't understand the answers on the topic that I've pointed out, please try to explain what you don't understand exactly.

Comment: what is $2^{\infty} \cdot \frac{1}{\ln(n)^{2}}$?? How do you get this?

Comment: Can you post me a link to the answer? Thank you!

Comment: The link is in my first comment.

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you, but I didn't under which test they used...

Comment: Honestly, I don't like the answers in the link provided. A simple test I can think of is compare $\sum \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}$ against $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$. The second series clearly diverges by integral test.

Comment: The accepted answer in the link gives you the answer by comparing your sum to $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Is it $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n^2)}$ or $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{2}}$? because $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)^{2}}$ does not show which one is meant.

Comment: Is the second one $(\ln(n))^2$

Comment: @achillehui - Your answer was very helpful!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For all $\alpha>0$ $$ \ln (n) =\mathcal{O} \left(n^\alpha \right).$$

Comment: What ???
I need to show it by using tests....

Comment: May I know why that is true?

Comment: @YoavFridman I'm sorry if you are not familiar with this approach. Solutions with tests have been given by others.

Comment: @yanbo Try applying l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @user1337 - It's OK! You don't have to sorry - you tried to help, and this is what important!!  :-).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log^2 n}{n} = 0 ~ \rightarrow ~ \sum_{k = m}^n \frac{1}{k} \leq \sum_{k = m}^n \frac{1}{\log^2 k} ~ \text{for all }n > m \text{ and some }m > 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

First,we compute the following limit
$\lim_{x \to +\infty }\frac{x}{(ln(x))^2}$

This limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. then by L' Hospital's Rule we have :

$\lim_{x \to +\infty }\frac{x}{(ln(x))^2}=\lim_{x \to +\infty }\frac{(x)'}{((ln(x))^{2})'}=\lim_{x \to +\infty }\frac{x}{2ln(x)}=\lim_{x \to +\infty }\frac{(x)'}{(2ln(x))'}=lim_{x\to+\infty}(\frac{x}{2})=+\infty$.

Consequently, for sufficiently large $x$ we have $\frac{x}{(ln(x))^2}>1$ which implies $\frac{1}{(ln(x))^2}>\frac{1}{x}$.

Applying the above result we deduce that for $n$ suffiently large, $\frac{1}{(ln(n))^2}>\frac{1}{n}$.

But the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, then by the Comparison Criterion we imply $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(ln(n))^2}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln k)^{2}} \text{converges} \iff \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{(\ln 2^k)^{2}} \text{converges}$$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{(\ln 2^k)^{2}} = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{(\ln 2^k)(\ln 2^k)}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k^2(\ln 2)(\ln 2)}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k^2(\ln 2)^2} \text{(diverges)}$$

So the original series diverges.

Comment: I try to use it..
I get something that was unclear...
What I should get if I'll use this test?

Comment: @YoavFridman : updated the answer.